# Silverlight 4 Business Application Architecture

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, crud

With the arrival of VS 2010 and Silverlight 4, I decided it's time to look into Silverlight and understand how to build a 3-Tier business application.

After several hours of searching for and reading documentation and tutorials, I'm thoroughly confused (and that doesn't happen easily).

Here are some specific points I don't understand.  I welcome guidance on any of them, and also would appreciate any references to a really good tutorial.

- Brad Abrahm's [What is a .NET RIA services](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/03/19/what-is-net-ria-services.aspx)  (written for Silverlight 3) seemed very promising, until I realized I don't have System.Web.Ria.dll on my system.  Am I missing an optional download?  Was this rolled into another DLL for Silverlight 4?  Did this go away in favor of something else in Silverlight 4?
- This [recent blog](http://wunnavabk.blogspot.com/) says to start from a Silverlight Business Application, remove unwanted stuff, create a WCF RIA services Class Library project, and copy files and references from the Business Application to the WCF RIA services project, while manually updating resource references (perhaps bug in B2 compiler).  Is this really the right road to go down?  It seems... clumsy.

My requirements are to perform *very simple CRUD* on straightforward business objects.

I'm looking forward to suggestions on how to do that the *Silverlight 4 way*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that since the silverlight application will be built on top of ASP.NET, the back-end would be the same for the application whether it was Silverlight or Html (WebForms/MVC)

You could have a look at the CSLA Business Object Framework that includes support for silverlight: http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/

Not sure 100% if its support Silverlight 4.0 yet, but if its doesnt I am sure it will soon.

Comment: @Mark: I have used CSLA for very large multi-tier projects in the past and am a big fan.  In fact, Rocky's ghost writer for the C# version of one of the CSLA books worked on that project with me.  It does seem a bit heavy though for what I'm trying to do.  Still, I'll have a look and thank you for the tip.

Comment: @Mark: Looks like version 4 of CSLA supports Silverlight 4.

Comment: @Eric J: If that was the C# 2005 book it was great! Read it front to back and implemented our own CodeSmith Templates with some tweaks, have subsequently dropped CSLA itself in our architecture but with some simularities, we also found it a bit to heavy-weight for what we needed, but still recommend it where I can...

Comment: Yes I think it was the 2005 one (would not have been 2008 in any event).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, the **System.Web.Ria** assembly has been replaced by these two assemblies:

```
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting
```

You can find a list of the breaking changes with the v1.0 release of WCF RIA Services [right here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RiaServices/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3570).

Comment: Thanks for that info.  Do you know of a really good RIA tutorial that explains what it is and isn't, and how to create RIA services?  The tutorials I have found so far seem very much "by example" and each cover a facet of RIA, but I'm having trouble piecing together the big picture.

Comment: @Eric: I too am just learning RIA services. The only videos I've watched are here http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices, and as you mentioned they are "by example."  Please let me know of any resources that have helped you learn about RIA services.

Comment: I just posted another Question to ask the community what resources they are using to learn WCF RIA Services:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866413/best-resources-to-learn-wcf-ria-services

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow that question.