# Best resources to learn WCF RIA Services

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

What books, videos, articles are you looking at to learn how to use the newly released [WCF RIA Services][1] for Silverlight?

Comment: Great question.  I'm struggling with getting the "big picture" of RIA services as well.  I have been over the official getting started stuff and what blogs I can find, and feel I only have pieces of the whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I will continue to update this list with community answers. Please let me know if you've found any useful material about WCF RIA Services.

### Starting Point

- [WCF RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/)

  - [Introduction to WCF RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/ria-services/net-ria-services-intro/) (video)
  - [RIAServices support in Visual Studio 2010](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-4-beta/ria-services-support-visual-studio-2010/) (video)
- [How to setup your DomainService using partial classes for easy maintenance](http://www.wcfriaservices.net/Blog/post/How-to-setup-your-DomainService-using-partial-classes-for-easy-maintenance.aspx) (article)

### MVVM with WCF RIA Services

- [Developing with WCF RIA Services Quickly and Effectively](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/CL09) (video)
- [Architecting Silverlight 4 with RIA Services, MEF and MVVM](http://wildermuth.com/2010/04/16/Updated_RIA_Services_MVVM_Example) (article)

Answer (score 2):

The starting point would be http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/

Sample code: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RiaServices

Answer (score 1):

This is a great training course with guided labs about WCF RIA Services with Silverlight 4: http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/Silverlight4/